# How to implement a method annotation to check some conditions before calling the method

Tags: c#, annotations

Assuming that I have this code

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    class Test
    {   
        private int someValue = 10;

        public void MethodA(){
            if(someValue == 10){
                Console.WriteLine("Method A");
            }
        }

        public void MethodB(){
            if(someValue == 100){
                Console.WriteLine("Method B");
            }
        }

        public void MethodC(){
            if(someValue == 1000){
                Console.WriteLine("Method C");
            } 
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = new Test();
        test.MethodA();
        test.MethodB();
        test.MethodC();
    }
}
```

Run the code, I can get "Method A" printed on the console screen.

But I want to refactor the class Test using method annotation.
I expect that the code will be

```
class Test{

    private int someValue = 10;

    [RunWhen(10)]
    public void MethodA(){
        Console.WriteLine("Method A");
    }

    [RunWhen(100)]
    public void MethodB(){
        Console.WriteLine("Method B");
    }

    [RunWhen(1000)]
    public void MethodC(){
        Console.WriteLine("Method C");
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to implement the anonation RunWhen, can someone help me. (Actually, I'm not sure can we do it with C# or not)

Thanks

Comment: You cannot - for regular methods - without using AOP (aspect orientated programming).